# Tensorflow: how to save variables and load them to different variables?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Let's say I have two identical networks, `A` and `B`. I saved (using `Saver`) a previous state of network `A`, and now I would like to load it into network `B` (all happens during the same run). How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me provide an example. First, let's define and save some variables:

```
import tensorflow as tf

v1 = tf.Variable(tf.ones(1), name='v1')
v2 = tf.Variable(2 * tf.ones(1), name='v2')

saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.trainable_variables())
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    saver.save(sess, './tmp.ckpt')
```

Now, let's define some variables with the same names in a new graph, and load their values from the checkpoint:

```
with tf.Graph().as_default():
    assert len(tf.trainable_variables()) == 0
    v1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(1), name='v1')
    v2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(1), name='v2')

    saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.trainable_variables())
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        saver.restore(sess, './tmp.ckpt')
        print(sess.run([v1, v2]))
```

The last line prints:

```
[array([1.], dtype=float32), array([2.], dtype=float32)]
```

Comment: As I haven't worked with several graphs at once yet, I wonder - can I use the output of one graph as the input of a placeholder for the second?

Comment: You can't use the output tensor of one graph as the input of another graph. However, you can execute the first graph within a session, obtain an output value, and then feed the placeholder of the second graph with this value. You can find more information about graphs and sessions [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/graphs).